# SQL query to get instructors and students has invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi I have a schema that look like this

[image: Image of the schema]

I made two queries that had to do this:

1. Find the names of the top 4 instructors who have taught the most number of distinct courses. Display also the total number of courses taught.

   - Output columns: `InstructorName`, `NumberOfCoursesTaught`
   - Sort by: `NumberOfCoursesTaught` in descending order
2. Find the top 2 students who have taken the most number of courses.

   - Output columns: `S_ID`, `StudentName`, `NumberOfCourses`
   - Sort by: `NumberOfCourses` in descending order

For query 1, I wrote:

```
SELECT name AS InstructorName, count(course_id) AS NumberOfCourses
FROM Teaches 
WHERE name IN (SELECT name FROM Instructor where Instructor.i_id = Teaches.i_id)
GROUP BU i_id
ORDER BY COUNT(course_id) DESC;
```

For query 2, I wrote

```
SELECT s_id as S_ID, name as StudentName, count(course_id) as NumberOfCourses
FROM Takes 
WHERE name IN (SELECT name FROM Student WHERE Takes.s_id = Student.s_id)
GROUP BY s_id
ORDER BY COUNT(course_id) DESC;
```

Both say:

> "NAME" Invalid identifier

Comment: Your queries are wrong. `Teaches` nor `Takes` does not have a column by the name `name`.

Comment: But I say where name IN and then another SELECT

Comment: Queries are wrong. You do not have a ‘name’ column in either table you are initially querying. You are going to have to rethink this entirely and perform joins between your tables.

Comment: Can someone help in making the two queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you should use another logic to build your queries. Here is a demonstration for the first query ; from there on, you should be able to create the second query (and maybe post it as an answer?).

---

Start with an aggregate query that computes the number of teaches per instructor id, looking at the `Teaches` table:

```
SELECT i_id, COUNT(*) cnt FROM Teaches GROUP BY i_id
```

Then rank each record by decreasing count, using window function `ROW_NUMBER()` :

```
SELECT i_id, cnt, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY cnt DESC) rn
FROM (SELECT i_id, COUNT(*) cnt FROM Teaches GROUP BY i_id) t
```

All that is left to do is get thte instructor name (`JOIN ON Instructor`) and filter in the top 4 records

```
SELECT i.name InstructorName, x.cnt NumberOfCoursesTaught
FROM (
    SELECT i_id, cnt, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY cnt DESC) rn
    FROM (SELECT i_id, COUNT(*) cnt FROM Teaches GROUP BY i_id) t
) x
INNER JOIN Instructor i ON i.i_id = x.i_id
WHERE x.rn <= 4
ORDER BY x.cnt desc
```

Comment: This gives an error at line 2 and says that SQL command not properly ended

Comment: @rshtate : which of the 3 query is giving this error ?

Comment: The first line in this one 

        SELECT i_id, cnt, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY cnt DESC) rn
FROM (SELECT i_id, COUNT(*) cnt FROM Teaches GROUP BY i_id) t

Comment: @rshtate : this is valid syntax... **[see this db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4214578d124c61cff17eba63fd15004c)**, there is no syntax error when running this query... Are you really running Oracle ? Which version ?

Comment: Yes running oracle: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: So : please check **[the fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4214578d124c61cff17eba63fd15004c)** : you can see that the queries do not generate syntax errors. Likely, there is some issue when you copy my code to wherever you execute it...

Comment: I copied it exactly line by line. are you missing ; or something somewhere except the end

Comment: @rshtate : yes, you can add a `;` at the end of the statement, depending on your SQL client that's mandatory or not. I feel like I will have trouble helping you more... I provided you with a step-by-step logic, working queries and a fiddle....

Comment: This not working for me currently i'll just wait for someone else to respond then. Thanks anyway